# Route bootstrap navbar items without changing text color

Tags: css, react-bootstrap

I am a beginner to bootstrap and I got stuck at a problem.
I want to route the navbar links to another components on react.js but When I do this
the text color turns blue. Is there any method to route any element without changing the
bootstrap predefined css.
Here is my screenshots.[Before routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpjwX.png)

[After routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoEMj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### CSS Solution also for React

1. Add className/class in the Link(React Router) tag only. (Most Important Part!! Add ClassName in Link tag not any other.)
2. Add text-decoration: none in the css file.

Nav.js

```
  <Link to="/" className="link" >
    Get Started
  </Link>
```

Nav.css

```
.link {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```